# NodeJS best performance possible when storing data when using web sockets

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, session, socket.io

I'm developing a turn based game with NodeJS and Socket.io in which a lot of information is stored between turns.

I'm wondering what is the best approach to handle lets say, thousands of users.

Currently I'm using global variables to store everything related to a match in a "duels" global variable with the key being the dynamically created room:

```
duels[room].character_1 = character_1;
duels[room].character_opponent_1 = character_opponent_1;
duels[room].player_1_moves = {//really big object};
duels[room].player_2_moves = {//really big object};
```

I'm not sure if this is an optimal way to handle thousands of users. At least Memory wise.

I've seen 2 other options:

1st: Using Session variables to store the data, however this seems to me will take a lot of memory of the server(RAM), whats better global variables or sessions? Or are they both pretty bad?

2nd: I'm using MongoDB, is it a viable option to insert and retrieve information constantly in my database and have it stored there? I have a sense that if I send too much queries to my database it will crash.

Basically, at this point I have no idea where to store all this information without risking my servers performance. I'm open to any approach.

Comment: Title seems a little ambiguous, but can't think of a better one

Comment: Leaving your data in memory will probably give you the best performance. If  there is too much data to hold in memory or you need to persist data, a database might be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When optimizing purely for performance, memory is always the best for performance as long as you have enough memory for what you are trying to do and as long as you aren't trying to share data between multiple server instances (as in clustering).

So, it really just comes down to how much memory are you consuming per user and how many users do you really need to support.  And, can you comfortably use that much memory in your server process without causing any issues.  Since you've provided none of the memory usage metrics for us to comment on, that is something you will have to measure and decide upon yourself.

Another option that you don't mention that would work with node.js clustering would be to use a separate redis process for storing/retrieving the data.  redis is an in-memory store, but because it's in another process, you can access it from multiple processes (it is compatible with node.js clustering) and it moves the RAM storage usage out of your node.js process.  You will still need to have enough RAM in the server to not cause issues, but getting the storage out of the node.js process can increase performance in node.js itself (less stuff to garbage collect) and may allow you to more efficiently use all the RAM resources of your server.